# How to use $wpdb global variable in multilple files inside theme folder?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a theme in which I have to use $wpdb object in multiple files. So should I create one global $wpdb variable in index.php file or should I create multiple global variables in the files?

Comment: Hey, @akash if you're talking about Wordpress then in wp $wpdb is already a declared globally by default you need to set it again. You can access it anywhere in the wp-theme files.

Comment: @GovindSoni Thanks for clarifying it. I have 1 more query...
$order = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_dashboard where uname=<<dynamic_name>>");..How to achieve this? Like I have tried it with giving $variable but its not working

Comment: function someFunction() {
 
global $wpdb;
 
//..................
 
//Some Operation on database using $wpdb
 
//..................
 
}

Comment: You just have to declare global $wpdb once in a file or a function and call it will accessible according to the block or entire file